# Kafka messages versioning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Currently I am implementing schema registry by myself. But maybe there is some other ways for kafka messages (payload) versioning? I know about confluent.io schema registry (and some other similar). So my question is: Is schema registry the only possible way to ensure message backward compatibility?

By the way is there any good library for converting java object from object and schema json's?

Answer (score 1):

[Confluent Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/index.html) provides versioning of your Avro schemas in Apache Kafka.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/schema-registry/docs/api.html#compatibility), schema registry supports 4 compatibility configurations and the default is backward compatibility:

> The schema registry server can enforce certain compatibility rules
>   when new schemas are registered in a subject. Currently, we support
>   the following compatibility rules.
>
> **Backward compatibility (default):** A new schema is backward compatible
>   if it can be used to read the data written in all previous schemas.
>   Backward compatibility is useful for loading data into systems like
>   Hadoop since one can always query data of all versions using the
>   latest schema.
>
> **Forward compatibility:** A new schema is forward compatible if all
>   previous schemas can read data written in this schema. Forward
>   compatibility is useful for consumer applications that can only deal
>   with data in a particular version that may not always be the latest
>   version.
>
> **Full compatibility:** A new schema is fully compatible if it’s both
>   backward and forward compatible.
>
> **No compatibility:** A new schema can be any schema as long as it’s a
>   valid Avro.

You can change the compatibility to e.g. `BACKWARD` using the following call

```
# Update compatibility requirements globally
$ curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
    --data '{"compatibility": "BACKWARD"}' \
    http://localhost:8081/config
```

And the response should be

```
{"compatibility":"BACKWARD"}
```

In order to serialise a Java Object to Avro, you can use [Java Reflection API](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/package-summary.html). For example, you can create the schema using:

```
Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(T);
```